# how upload laravel folder (with view files in public folders) to server

Tags: php, laravel

My laravel project has view files in public folders that are extended from resource folders.
The problem is when I upload to infinityfree server.
I upload the folder structure as follows.

htdocs -> all files in public folder .
-> laravel -> All laravel project files

so index file need to edit

```
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/laravel/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}
```

The problem is that cannot find view files in the public folder.
server says it cannot access to view files in public folder -> themes folder

[image]

if upload all folders directly into htdocs, it says 403 error.

So how can upload this laravel app?

here is folder structure
[image]

here is directory listing after edit htacess file.
[image]

how edit to see website directly,
here is env file

```
APP_URL=http://learnerschool.epizy.com
APP_DEBUG=true
IS_DEMO=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put all files to `/public_html` / `htdocs` or other folder when you must upload files
2. Create `.htacces` file in this folder
3. Copy this code to `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Screen with my `publc_html` folder structure:

[image]

Comment: when I rewriye as you show , it redirect to Directory listing . and if click public folder , show website page  with url ```http://learnerschool.epizy.com/public/```.I think ,it need some configuration more.plz help .I update question.